# Hardware for image processing (object recognition) from video

Tags: performance, image-processing, embedded, object-recognition

What I want to do is to recognize signs on roads using some embedded device with a cam. I was thinking about RaspberryPi 2b, but I don't know if it's power is sufficient. I don't have to analyze every frame of the video, but still the more frames per second I analyze the better especially with high movement speeds.

Question is: Are there any better boards, that could be used for a task like this? (it would be best if they could run Linux/Windows10 on themselves as I am going to use openCV)

Comment: I believe this question is off-topic because it is looking for a recommendation on hardware.

Comment: Yes I do. Did not know, that it's so bad. Sorry

Comment: At the same time I cannot see better place than SO to ask such a question.

Comment: I, too, am unsure of a better place. However, there is a place called software recommendations SE. But, if you choose to try that place out, I *urge you* to carefully read the help center.

Comment: Software is in it's name not by accident. They don't even mention anything like recomendation of software in how to make a good question guide. So I guess I am stuck. Thanks

Comment: hardware* not software. My apologies.

Comment: Check for other SE sites at - http://stackexchange.com/sites

Comment: Assuming efficient algorithms (which perhaps is a valid SO question), I would suggest that the RPi 2 is more than adequate for the application, especially if you use the GPU for some of the processing.  Are you talking about a limites set of symbolic road signs, or non-deterministic place-name or direction signs?  The latter being far more complex.

Comment: I am talking about simpler option. Just limites / stop sign and so on. Thank you for help really. I would vote you up, but unfortunatelly I guess I lost privilege to do so with this question :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for a problem like this you can try to over analyse it and try to pick the hardware before solving the problem.  but that is basically the cart before the horse.

first take some video

second digitize it or get it into your daily driver or whatever your preferred software development computer is

start working on the algorithms to solve whatever problem you want to solve, bearing in mind that eventually you want to embed this so you may need to lean more towards lighter weight libraries or roll your own vs heavyweight or operating system dependent solutions (feeding it into photoshop is not a solution, nor is some matlab thing).

you may find that you need better video, important info

eventually you get close to the algorithm and THEN or as you approach the algorithm you can either prototype it on some raspberry pi or beaglebone boards or use a simulator if man hours is cheaper for you that hardware.  how many operations per second or per sign or whatever, with some derating how many operations per second do I think i can do on platform X (which is not deterministic, even with experiments as one line of code changed could completely change the performance, esp if on the edge).  an instruction set simulator is not going to mimic the pipeline right, but you can take an open source one and modify it to count instructions or types of instructions branches vs non-branches, etc.  roughly convert that to clocks, etc.  again if hardware is more expensive than man hours.  at the price of a raspberry pi and beaglebone black or white it is hard to not just buy one and try it.

a valid stackoverflow question would be, I have this video clip and I am trying to detect whether the car has passed a road sign or not and here is my code but it doesnt work or here is my algorithm but it doesnt work.  once past that hurdle another so question could be, I have detected there is a sign in this frame but i cannot detect whether it is a stop sign or yield sign or other, here is my algorithm or code and here are my results and my expected results.  another valid so question would be I have this algorithm that works, but I am not able to optimize it for platform X I am close within N percent (needs to be a smallish number less than 20% for example) can this be optimized further.

Comment: yes you will need a camera you can interface to from one of these platforms and you can try that first if you like, again money vs man hours, expect to buy multiple solutions before you find one that works, depending on what and how you hook things up you might also end up frying something so you may have to buy replacements.

Answer (score 0):

Hardware For fast Object recognition

You can use Raspberry pi 4 with [Google's Usb Accelerator](https://coral.withgoogle.com/products/accelerator)